# Adding Auto PictureBox in C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

When I click a button in my C# application,it will add the PictureBox same Inline as well as same size side by side.
if the first row is full,it will pass to the bottom row.How can I do that?

Comment: please explain better your question

Comment: do you have a picturebox and you want to add another one on button click ? can you please explain more

Comment: @Sara Saeed-As you mentioned,I want to add another one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are after [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) - just put all the picture box controls inside such panel and it will behave like you want, adding side by side then expand when it is "full".

Related question:
[Populating a FlowLayoutPanel with a large number of controls and painting thumbnails on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470863/winforms-populating-a-flowlayoutpanel-with-a-large-number-of-controls-and-painti)